# range between two dates in elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

i have a question with filter, range and or with elastic search.

I have de document in elasticSearch with

```
    {
      startDate : myDate
      endDate : onOtherDateOr Nothing

    }
```

I Want to search for a range where now is after startDate, or Between startDate and endDate if endDate is defined. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 4):

I find below query as best approach:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "order.dateCreated": {
        "dateFrom": "2011-01-24",
        "dateTo": "2011-01-24"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this with two `bool/should` filters containing two nested `bool/must` filters:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [            <--- if endDate exists, check both bounds
                  {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "endDate"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "startDate": {
                        "lte": "now"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "endDate": {
                        "gte": "now"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [            <--- if endDate missing, only check startDate
                  {
                    "missing": {
                      "field": "endDate"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "startDate": {
                        "lte": "now"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: When i use this query, elastic maker a QueryParsingException, with no filter define for Should, could You Help Me

Comment: [{\"query\":{\"filtered\":{\"filter\":{\"geo_distance\":{\"distance\":\"1km\",\"geo\":{\"lat\":\"45.7677957\",\"lon\":\"4.8731638\"}},\"bool\":{\"should\":[{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"missing\":{\"field\":\"enDate\"}},{\"range\":{\"startDate\":{\"lte\":\"now\"}}}]}}]}}}},\"sort\":{\"_geo_distance\":{\"geo\":{\"lat\":\"45.7677957\",\"lon\":\"4.8731638\"},\"order\":\"asc\",\"unit\":\"km\",\"distance_type\":\"plane\"}}}]]] this is the request i use

Comment: Please update your question with the stack trace of the `QueryParsingException` you get, thx!

Answer (score 0):

try the next query, at least it works for me.`

```
"query": {
    "range": {
        "date_ field ": {  # this field_name should be the field where your date range 
                                        resides. 
                 "gte": startDate,
                  "lte": endDate,
                   "boost": 2.0
                      }
                    }
                  }`
```